# Upload file to specific directory PHP

Tags: php, file-upload, upload

I am trying to upload a file to a specific directory other then where my script is located.

Location of script:

```
mysite.com/mod/file/action/script.php
```

where I would like saved:

```
mysite.com/uploads/videos/
```

Script I'm trying to get working:

```
$target_dir = "mysite.com/uploads/videos/";
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["upload"]["name"]);
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["upload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)
```

I can't seem to ge this to work.  I am also using godaddy shared hosting if that helps.  How would this be done?

Comment: remove `mysite.com` from traget_dir

Comment: you can use dir path like "/root/site_dir/uploads/"

Answer (score 0):

Try it change the name of project_folder with your folder name

```
$target_dir = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'project_folder/uploads/videos/';
```

Comment: what would project_folder be?

Comment: if you are working on local it is a path to htdocs/project/uploads/videos/
if you have not any folder and working on base directory then remove project_folder

Comment: just echo $target_dir you will understand what remain in your path

Answer (score 0):

this,

```
$target_dir = "mysite.com/uploads/videos/";
```

Should be like this,

```
$target_dir = "../uploads/videos/";
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
$target_dir = "../../../uploads/videos/";
```

Answer (score 0):

Without the definition of `move_uploaded_file`, it's hard to be sure, but I'd presume that the destination is relative to *the current working directory (`.`)*.

The most reliable fix is to specify an absolute path, probably using `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` to find an appropriate start point, as shown in [Ahmed Ginani's answer](/a/43626599).